# Any good resources for drawing music notation with Obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer

Are there any good resources for drawing musical notation with something like core graphics? I have started drawing whole notes and a staff, and am somewhat comfortable with drawing now, but something as necessary a treble staff is a pretty amazing prospect right now and i would LOVE to find out that someone else has shared some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Musical notation is usually done with a font like Adobe Sonata or one of several freely-available alternatives.  Just google for "music font".

Comment: That makes sense, less doubling of effort, but I like the amount of control afforded by drawing notes, so i want to see how far i can take it. I am pretty sure i will use a font for everything clearly textual though

Comment: I guess this is all the answer I will get... alas. :-)